# nodejs callback don't understand how callback result come through argument

Tags: javascript, node.js

Seen and run code below, thought I understand closures... How that 'avatarUrl' in callback argument is received in 'avatar'which is function argument too. I know this is common pattern, just can't get it yet

```
var GitHubApi = require('github');
var github = new GitHubApi({
version: '3.0.0'
});

var getUserAvataWithCallback = function(user, callback) {
    github.search.users({q: user}, function(err,res) {
        if (err) { callback(err, null);}
        else {
            var avatarUrl = res.items[0].avatar_url;
            callback(null, avatarUrl);
         }
    });
};


getUserAvataWithCallback('irom77', function(err,avatar) {
    console.log('got url with callback pattern', avatar);
})
```

Comment: It's a standard *function call* right there: `callback(null, avatarUrl);`. No [notable] closures involved here.

Comment: `avatar` is not an argument, it's a *parameter* to that callback function.

Comment: so no closures here ? Doesn't 'getUserAvataWithCallback' closures 'github.search.users()'  ? I understand difference , avatar is parameter and 'avatarUrl' is argument, right . Still don't get how that avatarUrl is received into avatar, sorry..maybe that parentheses () confuse me

Comment: Well, `function(err,res) {…}` is a closure over the `callback` variable, yes, but that doesn't really matter for the call. `callback` refers to the `function(err,avatar) {…}` that you pass into `getUserAvataWithCallback`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, callbacks are an underlying and integral concept in javascript, so it is important that you understand a few concepts. Look at this example:

```js
// This is the function definition for "foo"

//here the callback argument refers to
//the second argument in the function call at
//the bottom which is a function

var foo = function(arg, callback) {
  
  if(arg%2 != 0)
    callback("arg is odd", arg)
    
  else
    callback(null, arg)
}
//Function call to foo
foo(2, function(err, num) {
  if(err)
    console.log(err)
  else
    console.log(num)
}
```

So, in the example above, you can think of the function call as a call with two parameters, the integer 2 and a function.

In the function definition:

The integer is referred to as "arg" and the function is referred to as "callback".

1. When callback("arg is odd", arg) is executed, the function is called with:

   - err = "arg is odd"
   - num = arg
2. When callback(null, arg) is executed, the function is called with:

   - err = null
   - num = arg

---

The important thing to remember here is that in javascript, functions can be passed as arguments to other functions. Do some further reading [here](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

Comment: Wow got it, sweet example I was looking for thnx a lot

Comment: Thnx again I just clicked

Answer (score 1):

The name of the argument passed to a function does not need to be the name of the argument in the definition of the function, the argument in the definition is the name of the variable that will be initialized inside the scope of given function. The argument declaration will receive the value passed at the second position of the function call (as per the code you've provided) and you will be able to access it inside the scope with that name. You can:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2);
}

foo(true, true); // will output true, true
foo(0, 1); //will output 0, 1
foo('shikaka', 1); //will output "shikaka", 1

var bar = "shikaka";
foo(bar, "shikaka"); //will output "shikaka", "shikaka"
```

Comment: I got this , but I understand how function works. Just don't get yet how function is included in function and suddenly parameters/arguments  return results lol ..sorry